# Batch use "=" as a string when passing argument

Tags: string, function, batch-file, operators, parameter-passing

funtion.bat echo variables

```
set "Var1=%1"
set "Var2=%2"
set "Var3=%3"

echo %Var1% %Var2% %Var3%
```

I use a batch that calls this function by passing 3 arguments

```
call function.bat blabla= argument2 TEST.txt
```

As you see my first argument has an equal sign in it. But I want to use it as a string and not as an operator.

When I run the batch this is the result that I get:

```
blabla
argument2
TEST.txt
```

This is the result that I want:

```
blabla=
argument2
TEST.txt
```

Does anyone have an idea of how to get "blabla="?

Comment: Double quote the argument, if necessary remove the quotes with `%~1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `cmd /?` in cmd:

> The special characters that require quotes are:
>       `<space>`
>       `&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~  `

As you can see, you should quote **almost everything** that contains `=` because it is used as a separator. You should run your batch file with the command:

```bat
call function.bat "blabla=" "argument2" "TEST.txt"
```

in cmd and then remove the double quotes for each argument using the following code (the `~` modifier):

```bat
set "Var1=%~1"
set "Var2=%~2"
set "Var3=%~3"

echo %Var1% %Var2% %Var3%
```

and it should work. This way is recommended for best practice. Do it always.